# null and string interpolation in C# 6

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I am using new C# 6.0 features String Interpolation for generating SQL statements.

```
$@"INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableName]([Column1], [Column2]) Values({item.property1}, {item.property2})";
```

If properties are null then generated SQL is the following

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableName]([Column1], [Column2]) Values(,)
```

And this cause an error. (Incorrect SQL).

I need Null instead of empty spaces. Can i somehow achieve this ?

Comment: Never mind the wrong syntax, using SQL concatenation is a very bad idea that exposes you to injection attacks. Use parameterized queries instead, eg `Values(@param1, @param2)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It's very-very draft version for demo. At the moment i do not care about security.

Comment: `{item.property1 ?? "Null"} `

Comment: What types are the columns? You can use the null coalescing operator (`item.property1 ?? defaultValue`) but you need to the right defaultValue.

Comment: @ChrisF There are a lot of types. For example int? , byte? , decimal?

Comment: @leppie If item.property1 is of type int? (for example) than code will not compile

Comment: @Disappointed you just need to pick the right default value for the type of column. There's no universal solution. For a string it would be `string.Empty`, for a decimal it would be `0`, etc.

Comment: At the moment, please do care about security because it's absolutely *trivial* to do *and* it solves your problem to boot -- `SqlParameter.Value = (object) object ?? DBNull.Value` will do the Right Thing.

Comment: @Disappointed.  It's not _just_ about SQL injection.  It's also about the appropriate handling of null values.  Or dates. Or strings.  Or string with apostrophes in them.  Or...  Switch to parameters and these problems become a _lot_ easier to solve.

Comment: –1 for not parameterizing sql, all sql must be parameterized

Comment: Parameterized queires are not just security. They solve the problem you're trying to solve way better than you will ever come up with in short term.

Answer (score 6):

`{Convert.ToString(item.property1) ?? "NULL"}` should do it. This is still broken, because you need very specific formatting for the SQL to come out right. You can solve the formatting yourself.

The usual SQL injection disclaimers have been given in the comments already. This approach is unsalvagable. You need to throw this away.

Comment: Yep, as long as none of the properties are actually strings or `DateTime` or `bool`, this should work fine. Fixing all these issues while still stubbornly refusing to use `SqlParameter` is left as an exercise to the reader...